# Turn Coffeescript loop using range into ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

*Disclaimer*: I don't know Coffeescript and, although I appreciate it has contributed towards the ES6 spec, I can't wait to see the back it.

This Coffeescript loop (wrote by someone else)

```
if @props.total>1
  for page in [1..@props.total]
    active = (page is +@props.current)
```

is, according to [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/), equivalent to this JS

```
var active, i, page, ref;

if (this.props.total > 1) {
  for (page = i = 1, ref = this.props.total; 1 <= ref ? i <= ref : i >= ref; page = 1 <= ref ? ++i : --i) {
    active = page === +this.props.current;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to use a `for..of` loop to shorten that JS, but I can't figure out how.

I've tried to implement [this idea](http://davidarvelo.com/blog/array-number-range-sequences-in-javascript-es6/)(the generator function bit at the bottom), but I can't get it right.

My question is: Is there a way of making ranges in ES6?

Comment: The `function* range` from the linked article should work (and no, there aren't many other ways to implement ranges). Please show us the exact code you tried.

Comment: A simple `for (let page = 1; page < this.props.total; page++)` loop would probably be the easiest solution. No need to use a `for of` loop here, even if that's the equivalent to Coffeescript's `for in`.

Comment: …and given that you set `active` to the last comparison anyway, you could omit the loop completely :-)

Comment: wait, wat? your last comment threw me a bit.

Comment: I guess that you actually have a different loop body that does more than assigning the `active` variable, but the snippet you've shown us could be reduced to `if (this.props.total > 1) active = this.props.total === +this.props.current;`

Comment: Sure. Let me see if I can get the generator code I have to make sense and post it.

Comment: Any update? Did you get it to work?

Comment: Nope. Still struggling to find a reasonable way of rendering that.

Answer (score 2):

The generator solution you are looking for would be

```
function* range(i, end=Infinity) {
    while (i <= end) {
        yield i++;
    }
}

// if (this.props.total > 1) - implicitly done by `range`
for (let page of range(1, this.props.total) {
    active = page === +this.props.current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For generating any range of sequential integers of length `k` starting at `n` in JavaScript the following should work:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(k)).map((x, i) => i + n);
```

While not *quite* the same as the coffeescript range functionality, its probably close enough for most uses. Also despite being significantly more verbose has one decided advantage: you don't have to remember which of `..` and `...` is exclusive and which is inclusive.