# Sum of range in Javascript in function local variable

Tags: javascript, function, closures, higher-order-functions, first-class-functions

I have range function and output functions they works correct,now I want create sum function for using as callbac function in range function,but when some function executed local variable let us say total or sum initialize 0(zero),how can solve this problem?

```
    function range(start,end,callback,step) {
        // body...
        step=step || 1;
        for(i=start;i<=end;i=i+step){
            callback(i);
        }
    }
    function output(a) {
        // body...
        console.log(a);
    }
    function sum(m){
       var total=0;
       // some code
}
    range(1,5,output);
    range(1,5,sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function range(start,end,callback,step) {
        // body...
        var aggregate;
        step=step || 1;
        for(i=start;i<=end;i=i+step){
            aggregate = callback(i, aggregate);
        }
    }
    function output(a) {
        // body...
        console.log(a);
    }
    function sum(m, aggregate){
       return m + aggregate;
    }
    range(1,5,output);
    range(1,5,sum);
```

This way you could even do cool stuff like

```
function conc(m, aggregate) {
    return aggregate + m.toString();
}

range(1,5,conc,2); //prints 135
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuition style code, like you've started it with range(), can get really weird and cumbersome.

And please, please, mind defining your local variables. like `i`

```js
function range(start,end,callback,step) {
  step=step || 1;
  for(var i=start; i<=end; i=i+step)
    callback(i);
}
    
function output(...label) {
  return function(...args){
    console.log(...label, ...args);
  }
}

function sum(callback){
  var total = 0;
  return function(value){
    //will log ever intermediate total, because sum() has no way to tell when the sequence is over.
    callback(total += +value || 0);
  }
}

range(1,5,output('range:'));
range(1,5,sum(output('sum:')));
```

In this case, I'd prefer using a generator instead, although the higher order functions get obsolete.

```js
function *range(start,end,step) {
  step = +step || (end < start? -1: 1);
  for(var value = start, count = (end - start) / step; count-- >= 0; value += step)
    yield value
}

function sum(iterator){
  var total = 0, v;
  for(v of iterator) total += +v || 0;
  return total;
}

console.log("range:", ...range(1,5))
console.log("sum of range:", sum(range(1,5)))

//just to show that this works with your regular array as well
console.log("sum of array:", sum([1,2,3,4,5])); 

//and some candy, as requested by Bergi ;)
//I like to stay with the interfaces as close as possible to the native ones
//in this case Array#reduce
var fold = (iterator, callback, start = undefined) => {
  var initialized = start !== undefined,
    acc = start,
    index = 0,
    value;
  
  for(value of iterator){
    acc = initialized?
      callback(acc, value, index):
      (initialized=true, value);
    ++index;
  }
  if(!initialized){
    throw new TypeError("fold of empty sequence with no initial value");
  }
  return acc;
}
//and the ability to compose utility-functions
fold.map = (callback, start = undefined) => iterator => fold(iterator, callback, start);

console.log(" ");

var add = (a,b) => a + b; //a little helper
console.log('using fold:', fold(range(1,5), add, 0));

//a composed utility-function
var sum2 = fold.map(add, 0);

console.log('sum2:', sum2( range(1,5) ));
```

Comment: One still could write a higher-order fold for iterators and use that to implement `sum` :-)

Comment: @Bergi, I'm not sure I get it. Do you mean like implementing fold for iterators and then `fold(iterator, (a,b)=>a+b)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly (but don't forget the `0`)

Comment: @Bergi, done. I've made the start-value optional (like in Array#reduce) and added proper logic to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a `range` function should not take a callback but [be a generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39804615/1048572) in modern JavaScript, however you were asking how to write such a callback.

You've already tagged your questions with [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572), and they are indeed the way to go here. By initialising a new `total` within each call of the outer function, you don't need to worry about how to reset a global counter.

```
function makeSum() {
    var total=0;
    return function(m) {
        total += m;
        return total; // so that we can access the result
    }
}

var sum = makeSum();
range(1, 5, sum);
output(sum(0));
```

Comment: this code works correct.But tell me how this code works? why u create makeSum() without arguments?   in last line code what does zero do?

Comment: `makeSum` is called without arguments because it takes no parameters. The zero (being passed as `m`) is just there to not further increase the sum, the only aim of that call is to get the `total` back (there might be other ways to achieve that, but using `sum` seemed to be the shortest solution).

Answer (score 0):

Won't simply calling the callback on the range array suffice if the callback is not undefined? Like this:

```
> function range(n, callback) {
    const r = [...Array(n).keys()]
    if (callback) {
      return callback(r)
    }
    return r
  }

> function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  }

> range(10)

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

> range(10, sum)

> 45
```